# Which version of Safari is in Mac OS Lion?

Tags: macos, safari

As far as I know, Lion was to ship with the next version of Safari which would be Safari 6. However, I cannot find any information about a new version of Safari...

So, does Lion ship with Safari 6 or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lion ships with Safari 5.1.

Apple releases updates to Safari independently of Mac OS X. The next version of Safari will be released sometime in the future (when Apple finishes it), and will be a free download for Mac and Windows.

[image]

Comment: Aha, I see `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The version of Safari that ships with Lion is 5.1.